# How to create Zip and upload files to it on google storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, gzip

Using `NodeJs v12`, We have multiple files creating dynamically for every minute, these files should be uploaded to cloud storage as `zip`, and this zip files should be updated with new files which are created on my system.

I have referred some docs, it says there is no directory concept in GCS, then how can we archive it?, We have observed that `gzip` added for files/object.

using `@google-cloud/storage` latest.

Current code:

```
storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(destinationStorage, {
     gzip: true,
     destination: userId+"/"+filename,
     metadata: {
         cacheControl: 'no-cache'    
     },
}).then( async(result) =>{
     console.log("Uploaded");
})
```

Comment: i'm not sure to understand your problem? Is it a compression problem? An archiving/upload issue? or a file organisation in GCS?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - it's about two things, one is how to compress on GCS with multiple files, second is how to edit the compressed files to add new files.

Answer (score 4):

In GCS, you can only create, read and delete object. It's not a file system. You can't move (even if you have the option, it's only a create elsewhere and delete the origin) and you can't update the content (you can [create a new version if you activate the versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning), but you can't change an existing content)

So, now you understand that you can't update an existing zip to add a file in it. You have to upload it again, with the whole content.

About ZIP and GZIP. It's 2 different things that you don't have to mix up. GZIP compresses only 1 file, ZIP compress files **AND** can create a package with 1 or several files/folders in it.

So you can't add several files into GZIP, only in ZIP. And ZIP isn't native to GCS, you have to handle the ZIP compression/file management on your side before sending the blob to GCS.

Anyway, I have the feeling that I have cleared up some misunderstood parts but not solved your issues. Don't hesitate to comment if you want more help!

Comment: your answer is very useful, found a npm package called "zip-bucket" but the problem is, it copies and merging only bucket files, not local files, also they tested upto 100 MB, and there is a possibility of a timeout error.